# pandas: map to new column, excluding some codes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of keys and values. I want to "map" the numbers in a dataframe column, where the original column is the keys and the new column is the values.

However, any values that are *not* included in the dictionary should be coded as 999.

Original dataframe:

```
     Col1
0    02
1    03
2    02
3    02
4    04
5    88
6    77
```

Dictionary:

```
codes = {'01':'05',
         '02':'06',
         '03':'07',
         '04':'08'}
```

Expected output:

```
>>> df['ColNew'] = df['Col1'].map(codes)

     ColNew
0    06
1    07
2    06
3    06
4    08
5    999
6    999
```

I'm not sure how to do this, other than to include the 999 codes in the dictionary in the first place. That's frustrating when there are over a hundred codes involved and only a few of them need to be anything other than 999.

Comment: Shouldn't the value at index four in your new output be `'08'`, considering the mapping you propose in `codes`?

Comment: I fixed that, sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `map` and [**`dict.get`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)
[**`dict.get`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) allows you to pass a default value in the event the `key` doesn't exist.

```
df['ColNew'] = df['Col1'].map(lambda x: codes.get(x, 999))

df

  Col1 ColNew
0   02     06
1   03     07
2   02     06
3   02     06
4   04     08
5   88    999
6   77    999
```

This will also preserve the `dtypes`.  In this case it doesn't matter because the `dtype` of the column is `object`.

However, if it were `int`, `map` would turn it into `float` when `NaN` came back.  By having a default value, we avoid the type conversion.

Comment: I was expecting `na_action` on `map` to `fillna` but it doesn't seem to work at all, even with NaN

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

*Note*: This is an inferior answer to that of piRSquared due to the type conversion:

You can simply fill the NaNs afterwards.

```
df['ColNew'] = df.Col1.map(codes).fillna('999')
```

Result:

```
     ColNew
0    06
1    07
2    06
3    06
4    05
5    999
6    999
```

---

One interesting thing is that the `na_action` parameter to [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) *is not* used as a default mapping argument, as I was originally tempted to think.

Its purpose is actually to control whether NaN values are affected by the mapping function - if you didn't map them in any way, you would see a potential performance increase by setting `na_action='ignore'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to skin this cat:

```
new_codes = {k: codes[k] if k in codes else '999' for k in set(df['Col1'])}
df['ColNew'] = df['Col1'].map(new_codes)

df
Out[126]: 
  Col1 ColNew
0   02     06
1   03     07
2   02     06
3   02     06
4   04     08
5   88    999
6   77    999
```

Some timings:

```
%timeit df['Col1'].map({k: codes[k] if k in codes else '999' for k in set(df['Col1'])})
1000 loops, best of 3: 373 µs per loop

%timeit df['Col1'].map(lambda x: codes.get(x, 999))
10000 loops, best of 3: 133 µs per loop

%timeit df.Col1.map(codes).fillna('999')
The slowest run took 92.77 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 575 µs per loop
```

Looks like [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43395437/5015569) is about 64% faster than mine!